# WP All Import: set the value of an ACF as the "ID" of the post with which it has a relationship

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

In my Wordpress project I have two Custom Post Types: "**Regioni**" and "**Comuni**".

"Regioni" is linked to the ACF group: "Nome" and "Codice ISTAT".

"Comuni" is linked to the ACF group: "Nome", "Regione" and "Cantiere". The "Regione" field is of type "**post_object**" and is filtered according to the custom post type "Regioni".

I am using the **WP All Import** plugin to perform CSV bulk uploads.

In this case, I'm importing a CSV for the "Comuni" post type. I would like to change the value of the ACF "Regione" from textual format (name of the region) to **the ID of the post_object with which it has a relationship.**

This is the function I used in the Function Editor:

```
function convertRegioneToID($regione){
    
    $args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'regioni',
    'meta_key'      => 'nome',
     'meta_value' => $regione,
    'meta_compare'  => '=',
    );
    
    $regionPosts = get_posts($args);
    
    if(empty($regionPosts)) return;
    
    $regionPostId = $regionPosts[0] -> ID;
    
    update_field('regione', $regionPostID);

    
}
```

Then I call the function in the "Regione" field:
[image]

The function is saved correctly without any errors.

The problem is that, when I then check the JSON of the results, the "Regione" field is empty or with the wrong "ID".

Where am I doing wrong?

Sorry for the perhaps stupid question, but this is the first time I interface with Wordpress and PHP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Where am I doing wrong?

You made your function directly update the database, instead of having it *return* the value that WP All Import should use for the field.

Check the examples & description under https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/inline-php/ - your function must *return* the value, that WAI will then insert into the field.

Your function is currently making the database update itself, and then returns *nothing* - and WAI then takes that "nothing", and sets it as the field value, undoing the update your function just made.